# Botón 'Comenzar' en bot para Messenger con Node.js

Tags: facebook

Buenas!

Estoy haciendo un bot para Facebook Messenger con Node.js, y me ha surgido una duda, cuando interactúo con otros bots desarrollados con plataformas como Api.ai o chatfuel, éstos al inicio muestran un botón 'comenzar' para que el bot muestre su mensaje de inicio, sin embargo no encuentro el modo de hacerlo a través de código

¿Alguien sabe como podría hacer que aparezca dicho botón nada más abrir el chat con el bot?

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema... Pudiste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/get-started-button/

ahi esta , para activarlo solo  necesitas enviar una peticion post solo una vez con el token de tu app de facebook

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ 
   "get_started":{
      "payload":"GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD"
    }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=aquiel token"
```

Comment: puedes explicarlo mejor... eso dice la documentación pero usando nodejs no dice claramente como ni donde..

Comment: en el boton no es necesario implementarlo en nodejs solo tienes que hacer una peticion post a este url "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=aquiel token" solo se hace una vez enviado como parametros un dato de tipo json  : { 
   "get_started":{
      "payload":"GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Si lo tienes como yo y usaste la guia del "inicio rápido", esto te servirá.

en el callback de tu `app.get('/webhook', callback )` yo use esto

```
request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile',
    qs: { access_token: access_token },
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
        get_started: {
            payload: 'GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD'
        }
    }
}, function(e, r, b){
    if (!e) {
        console.log(r)
    }
})
```

Para el de de saludos es lo mismo... pero lo puede usar en el json misma consulta asi:

```
json: {
    greeting:[
        {
            locale: 'default',
            text: 'Hola, soy el bot. Bienvenido.'
        }
    ],
    get_started: {
        payload: 'GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD'
    }
}
```

> Tienes que reiniciar el **ngrok** si lo estás utilizando.

Answer (score -1):

Ejemplo en *PHP*:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=TOKEN",

  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",

  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,

  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,

  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,

  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",

  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{ \r\n  \"get_started\":{\r\n 
   \"payload\":\"Empezar\"\r\n  }\r\n}",

  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(    "cache-control: no-cache",    "content-type: application/json",

  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);


if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;

} else {

  echo $response;

}
```